# uninitialized constant User::CompaniesRate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie in rails. I am trying to generate a page form. but I am geting this error.

I could not understand where is my problem.

this was the error showing and it was highlighting in this line

```
@companies_rates =@user.companies_rates
```

Here I will be having userpage, companies_rate and page3 where each pages have user id and companies rate has an column same column also exit in the page 3. Now i want display companies_rate and page 3 seperately

```
NameError in UsersController#show 

uninitialized constant User::CompaniesRate 

 @user = User.find(params[:id])
@companies_mines= @user.companies_mines
**@companies_rates =@user.companies_rates**
@title=@user.name
end
```

Here is my users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])

  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @companies_mines= @user.companies_mines
    @companies_rates =@user.companies_rates
    @title=@user.name

  end



  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to skillable"
      redirect_to @user

    else
      render 'new'

    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user

    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url

end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
  end
```

And here is my companies_rate controller

```
class CompaniesRatesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy


 def index
        @companies_rates = companies_rates.all
    end

    def show
        @companies_rates  = companies_rate.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @companies_rates  = companies_rates.new
    end

    def create
        @companies_rates  = companies_rates .new(params[:company,:r1,:r2,:r3])

        if @post.save
            redirect_to companies_rates _path,  :notice => "Your post was saved"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update

    end

    def destroy

    end

    private

    def companies_rates_params
      params.require(:companies_rates).permit(:company, :r1, :r2, :r3 )
    end

    def correct_user
      @companies_rates = current_user.companies_rates.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @ompanies_rates.nil?
    end
end
```

Here is my users modal

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  #attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :companies_mines
  has_many :companies_rates
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end


  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

Here is my companies_rates

```
class CompaniesRates < ActiveRecord::Base
    #attr_accessible :company, :r1, :r2, :r3

    belongs_to :user
  validates :company, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  default_scope :order => 'companies_rates.created_at DESC'


end
```

Can any on tell what is my problem and how to solve it.

Comment: post your user model if you can. Do you have a relationship between users and company rates set up?

Comment: is the `CompaniesRate` a model?

Comment: Update your question with more info.

Comment: Hi I have added the more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change the model name to CompaniesRate.Model name should be singular